# How to iterate through array of Images in SwiftUI eloquently?

Tags: image, loops, swiftui

I'd like to iterate through array of Images  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/image

in manner like List(images) or ForEach(images) but not through indexes of the array

```
List(images, id : \.hashValue){ $0 }
```

for using List or ForEach, Image must be hashable or identifiable

```
extension Image: Hashable{
     public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine( / some value / )
    }
}
```

what'd better to use as a parameter for "combine" ? or any suggestions how to implement looping eloquently ?

Comment: Try using ```List(images, id : \.self)```

Comment: id needs to be a property of the data that is a unique identifier it can't be the data itself

Comment: SwiftUI views react to changes in models that represent data. Image is a View it doesn’t act or behave like data, you can iterate over UIImage or NSImage.

Comment: Also Image does not have any value for any other layer of an application. It doesn’t not belong in anything related to Combine.

Answer (score -1):

How about wrapping each image in an `Identifiable` struct, and then using the `id` as the hash value…

```
struct ImageModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(id)
    }
    let id = UUID()
    let image: Image
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let images = [ImageModel(image:Image(systemName: "questionmark")),
                  ImageModel(image:Image(systemName: "square")),
                  ImageModel(image:Image(systemName: "circle"))]
        
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(images) { model in
                model.image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's possible but I'm trying to find the short cut Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by a short cut?

Comment: I mean less code

Answer (score -1):

SwiftUI is a declarative language and asking how to iterate something is imperative so it's not possible.